# Auto adjust the height of container based on content

Tags: html, css

Every time i put a huge content details, such as text it goes out of my container.How can i make the container height auto adjustable based on content;.

```
   #container {
    background-color: #262626;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
   border-top-left-radius: 30px;
   border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

    #main {
    position: relative;
    top: 116px;
    width: 980px;
    height: 700px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #262626;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#262626,#101010); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#262626,#101010); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#262626,#101010); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#262626,#101010); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px black;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please include your html too.... Render Markup

Comment: Ok i'll include it now

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/CqB3d/278/) is pretty cool or 'normal' would be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/zrBGw/862/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `#Main` css you've set your height to `700px`.

Change this to

```
height:auto;
```

and it will work fine. But since this is the default value anyway, you could also remove this height declaration completely, instead.

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/8xLz2k60/)

---

Or, if you wanted to have a **minimum height** of `700px`, say;

```
min-height:700px;
```

---

Of course, there are many other 'versions' of height you can set. Including (but not limited to):

- **min-height**

*The min-height CSS property is used to set the minimum height of a given element. It prevents the used value of the height property from becoming smaller than the value specified for min-height.*

- **max-height**

*The max-height CSS property is used to set the maximum height of a given element. It prevents the used value of the height property from becoming larger than the value specified for max-height.*

- **line height**

*On block level elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.*

All of which can be used to set you elements in a way you want

---

Here's a [Reference link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/height/) for you.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#Summary) summary of the height property

Comment: height:auto on main will shrink main container when content is lesser than 700px, which is presumably undesired. Probably a min-height:700px on #main as suggested in my answer is a better option

Comment: OP says 'auto-adjustable'. But will edit to include alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Use height: auto in your CSS. It will automatically adjust your height as your text gets bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any height in your CSS except if needed.
Default value of the property `height` is `auto` so you don't have to set it explicitly and as stated by previous answer of Ibtehaz, it'll adjust to content.

- *If* you've to set an height, by example because there's a tall background that would be cropped when there isn't enough content in a particular page, prefer the property `min-height`.
- `line-height` is useful in cases like `inline-block` and a few others.
- With HTML tables displaying tabular data and elements displayed in CSS with a table layout algorithm (`display: table-cell` and such), `height` has the same effect as `min-height` in the general case.
- As a last resort, `height` can be useful, for example with elements containing an image of set dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is that your container is inside #main.

As #main has a height of 700px, each time you get a content that is bigger than 700px, your #container is maxed and your content gets outside your main div.

To fix this just change the height of #main from height:700px to min-height:700px

Comment: there's no markup. How can you say the OP's `#container is inside #main`

Comment: @MrCoder Because this would explain what is happening to him and the names of the ids are quite self-explanatory.

Comment: @MrCoder In fact, if you check the validated answer it's assuming the same (although jbutler is not specifying it), so we should be correct in our assumption of the problem being the fixed height on #main.